# Xcode auto layout device screen issue

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm currently having problems with Xcode's constraints and alignment functionality. My current situation is trying to have 4 image views 
( the 1x, 2x, 5x, 10x ) sit in a perfect square arrangement, as it does when displayed on an iphone7,6,5. But when I move it to an iPhone x or even an older generation phone with a different screen aspect ratio, the square arrangement skewers and goes into an arrangement correlated to the screen parameters. [image]
[image]

The current constraints and alignments are as so..

Light Grey Background Box -

- Width = superview width x 0.8
- Height = ' is given by the 1:1 ratio constraint '
- position/alignment = width & height of superview with multiplier of 1. 
  ( so it's just centre of the screen )

The 4 image views -

- width = lightgreybackgroundbox x 0.38
- height = lightgreybackgroundbox x 0.38 
  ( size of the image views entirely dictated by the size of the grey background box ).
- alignment X position = lightgreybox centreX x 0.65
- alignment Y position = lightgreybox centreY x 0.8 
  ( this is just an example of the top left image view )

The position of the image views are dictated by selecting they have the same horizontal & vertical centre as that of the light grey box ( instead of the superview), and adjusting the multiplication value to position them all within the light grey background box ).

I then would think this would NOT cause issues as the height and width of the light grey box do NOT change, as they will always have the same aspect ratio, therefor the positioning of the image views would look the same and be consistent on every device. ( but their not, the image views and their positioning are still being dictated by the device aspect ratio ).

Are there any solid ways to configure image views in a way that they always keep their shape and spacing consistant on every device?
All I want is to have the first image example look the same on every device, without the clear distortion shown in the second example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to use `Stack Views`

Comment: Exactly what you want?

Comment: I must be missing something. Both screenshots look the same to me. Centered, adapted to the correct screen size... what's the problem?

Comment: Place your 4 views inside the StackView....

Comment: Unless I uploaded the 2 same images, the iphone x version has a clearly larger space between the top and bottom 2, while being closer to the edges. Iv'e tried using stack views, but the issue accurs.

Comment: It's all good I found a solution with stack views, have made a few stupid mistakes. Thanks for the help anyways